# Are `less textfile | col` and `cat textfile` the same?

Tags: cat, less

Do `less textfile |  col` and `cat textfile` accomplish the same thing?

I wonder if `man mysql | col -b > textfile` and `man mysql > textfile` do the same?

Comment: Do you have an example in mind that you're asking these about?

Comment: Yes, see my edit.

Comment: I would say that given you're piping the output to `col -b` that they're different, in the sense, that if there are any backspaces within the output, the `col -b` will strip them away.

Answer (score 2):

That's completely different, since `less` may do various kinds of transformation, e.g. via `$LESSOPEN`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite the same, since when `col` can do something with output from `less`.

The important point here, `less` will copy input file to output if its output is not a tty. You can see in [less-451 - main.c - line 222](https://github.com/Distrotech/less/blob/master/main.c):

```
    /*
     * Set up terminal, etc.
     */
    if (!is_tty)
    {
        /*
         * Output is not a tty.
         * Just copy the input file(s) to output.
         */
        SET_BINARY(1);
        if (nifile() == 0)
        {
            if (edit_stdin() == 0)
                cat_file();
        } else if (edit_first() == 0)
        {
            do {
                cat_file();
            } while (edit_next(1) == 0);
        }
        quit(QUIT_OK);
    }
```

So, to do the same as `cat file`, you can:

```
less file | grep ^
```

Comment: Even if `less` doesn't do anything special, your `less file | grep .` example is wrong, as `grep .` will/may filter out lines that do not contain valid characters.

Comment: @vinc17: Oh, my mistake, fixed it.